# Simply edit Sharepoint webpart manifest.json

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, manifest.json, sharepointframework

Probably simple to solve for anyone who is convident with that.

Sharepoint 2019 > Webpart > edit manifest file

Is there a way to simply edit the manifest file to activate the full bleed support like mentioned in the [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column) ?
I know that there is an article series to [create your own webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part), but it wasnt my intention to evolve myself to an full size web developer and install tons of software to edit a small variable =/ Simply edit this freaking manifest file from the embed-Webpart (modern experience).

If any How To's exists to open and edit (not create a complete new webpart -.-") the manifest file with visual studio or maybe a simply text editor, would be also a way, but I did not find anything.

Any help or links would be nice =/

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit SPFX webpart manifest.json, you can use Visual Studio Code as text editor.

Open the manifest.json under the path ..\src\webparts\webpartname and edit in VS Code Editor:

[image]

Update as we discussed：

"if you want a built in web part full width, another workaround would be using Modern Communication Site, this site template is full width by default, so the added OOTB WebPart will also be full width without left navigation."

"For Full Width section, yes, it's only available for specific web parts like hero, image. In this case, you can use One Column, although it's not really full width, but the communcation site have hidden the left navigation. Otherwise, you will need to create custom SPFX Web Part to enable full width."

Comment: thx your reply, but i ran an search over the entire server and cant find any folder(s) with the structure "src\webparts"
which root should have these folders?

Greetings

Comment: The folder should be existed in SPFX Web Part solution, are you using the SPFX WebPart ?

Comment: I am not really sure about what you mean with "SPFX Web Part solution" (do you mean Visual Studio Code?) and "SPFX WebPart". Iam not very familar with that area so maybe some basic facts in my understanding are fundamentally wrong. But in my understanding it should be possible to enable the full-bleed support for the embed-webpart of modern sharepoint sites from a 2019 on-premise server. Is My idea basically correct?

Comment: The demo in your original question is for SPFX WebPart not for OOTB built in web part in SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Microsoft ... -.-" (I thought, this is the same) So is there no way to change the behaviour of the ootb embed-webpart to use the full width? If no, are there recommended sources to get a similar code (to recreate is as an spfx webpart by me)? Thx for your patience =/ =)

Comment: The built in web part didn't release the source code, if you want to modify the property, it's necessary to build a custom SPFX Web Part with Node.js. And you can find some sample SPFX Web Part source code from GitHub:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples

Comment: And if you want a built in web part full width, another workaround would be using Modern Communication Site, this site template is full width by default, so the added OOTB WebPart will also be full width without left navigation.

Comment: The github link looks good (thx), i will have look later. For your second answer, i want to test some points an will come back later. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

> And if you want a built in web part full width, another workaround would be using Modern Communication Site, this site template is full width by default, so the added OOTB WebPart will also be full width without left navigation.

But that is exectly my problem from my first post. What i did:

1. create new web application
2. create communication site
3. edit the homepage of new communication site
4. add a new section with one column (doesnt use entire width, see picture)
5. add a new section with full width column (does use entire width, see picture)

And then, inside the section with full width i can only use die picture-webpart and the hero-webpart. For me it is not possible the choose other webparts in this "full width" column.
So, is that the normal behaviour?

Picture with single column and "full width column":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONy7M.png

Comment: For Full Width section, yes, it's only available for specific web parts like hero, image.

In this case, you can use One Column, although it's not really full width, but the communcation site have hidden the left navigation.

Otherwise, you will need to create custom SPFX Web Part to enable full width.

Comment: ok, now i get it. Thank you so much for your answers and patience ! ! ! But, is there a way to promote your comment to an answer, that i can accept it? Or should i edit my answer and insert yours and then accept it?

Comment: I will update my post above like we discussed, then you could accept my post as answer.
Thanks . You are very nice friend :)

Comment: you too ^_^   (filling up to reach the minimum character count xD)